# Problem with different "execution context" of an anonymous method within a loop

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-methods

I have a problem with an anonymous method within a loop.

The following code is just to illustrate my problem:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> bassists = new List<string>(){
        "Jaco Pastorius", 
        "Marcus Miller", 
        "Flea", 
        "Vicor Wooten"
    };

    foreach (string item in bassists)
    {
        this.button1.Click += (s, ea) => Output(s, ea, item); 
    }
}

private void Output(object s, EventArgs e, string item)
{
    this.listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And when I click into the button, the output is:

> Victor Wooten
>   Victor Wooten
>   Victor Wooten
>   Victor Wooten

instead of:

> Jaco Pastorius
>   Marcus Miller
>   Flea
>   Vicor Wooten

The main point of my problem is the differents execution context. I know my example is stupid.

Comment: Jaco Pastorius, Marcus Miller, Flea and Victor Wooten. One of these is not like the others....

Comment: 4 different styles... but i like them all !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the captured variable problem. Fix it by changing

```
foreach (string item in bassists)
{
    this.button1.Click += (s, ea) => Output(s, ea, item); 
}
```

to

```
foreach (string item in bassists)
{
    string currentItem = item;
    this.button1.Click += (s, ea) => Output(s, ea, currentItem); 
}
```

Here is an explanation of the issue: [Closing over loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). By putting the local variable `currentItem` in the scope of the loop and closing over that, we now capture that variable instead of the loop variable.

Comment: You can also use an indexed loop

Comment: @Falcon: What would be the advantage of using an indexed loop?

Comment: @Cody: I guess Falcon meant that using a `for(int i...)` the string would be necessary inside the scope ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating new handlers in the loop, that is unnecessary and dangerous.

Also you are creating an anonymous method which has the value in the loop hard-coded. That is worse.

Answer (score 0):

In whatever cases Jason's answer is correct. It is problem of variable capturing. This will majorly occur in two situation Threading and Anonymous methods